# How to export a listView to a txt file?

Tags: c#

I'm starting to program in C# and I want to export the data of a ListView to a txt-file, I have this code, but it does not export the data to the txt-file when I press the button destined for this task.

```
private void export2File(ListView lv, string splitter)
{
    string filename = "";
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    sfd.Title = "SaveFileDialog Export2File";
    sfd.Filter = "Text File (.txt) | *.txt";

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filename = sfd.FileName.ToString();
        if (filename != "")
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", item.SubItems[0].Text, splitter, item.SubItems[1].Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Is `export2File` method being called?

Comment: Maybe i did not know how to explain
I want the contents of the listView to be saved in a txt-file

Comment: You explained well, I could understand what you want. I asked what error are you getting?